# Aggregate one measure by another in MS Analysis Services

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap-cube

There is a CUBE with two measures Prices, Volumes and dimension Hours. (The real CUBE is much complex, this is a simplified version.)

```
Hours   Prices  Volumes
0       0       100
0       10      20
0       20      300
0       40      100
0       50      50

1       0       500
1       20      50
1       25      200
1       40      30
1       50      10
```

How to aggregate Volumes by Prices and get next result (probably by using MDX query):

```
Prices  Volumes
0       600
10      20
20      350
25      200
40      130
50      60
```

Comment: The easiest approach would be to create an attribute from the prices. Then SSAS would handle everything automatically. Note that this does not mean that the price cannot at the same time be a measure.

Comment: @FrankPl Yes, that's what I have done. At first I thought it should be done using MDX.